# Struts 2 interceptor that runs after the page executes?

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor

I'm using Struts 2. Using an interceptor, I create a database connection at the start of each page execution.

So for example, if a user goes to "myAction.do", it will create the database connection and then call `myAction.do` method.

What I'm looking for now is an interceptor or any other way to automatically call a method after the page execution, which will close the database connection.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In interceptor you can write pre processing and post processing logics.

Pre processing logic will execute before the action executes and
post processing logic executes after the action executes.

> Struts2 provides very powerful mechanism of controlling a request
>   using Interceptors. Interceptors are responsible for most of the
>   request processing. They are invoked by the controller before and
>   after invoking action, thus they sits between the controller and
>   action. Interceptors performs tasks such as Logging, Validation, File
>   Upload, Double-submit guard etc.

Whatever you will write after `invocation.invoke();` that will execute after executes action

[**SEE HERE FOR EXAMPLE**](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts2-interceptors-tutorial-with-example/)

Comment: I understand that `intercept()` is called pre-processing, but what method is called post processing? Is `destroy()` always called post processing for every request, or just once in a while?

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me. One more question, what if I wanted to run a custom method of the action, e.g if I wanted to run `myAction.setSomeValue()` just before `invocation.invoke()`, do you know how that could be done?

Comment: sorry i dont that.Normally i will specify in the struts.xml

Comment: NP. To do that you do `(MyAction) action = invocation.getAction()`,then run `action.setSomeValue()`

Comment: just posted it in case someone in future needs it ;)

Comment: That will fail if your interceptor ever gets called for an action that doesn't implement the setSomeValue() method. You should implement an interface on your action myAction implements MyInterface and then test for that interface in the interceptor using the instanceof keyword and only call the setSomeValue() method if the action implements the interface

Comment: @user497087 Yep, that's the way I'm doing it, in my example `MyAction` is the super class which all my other actions extend

Answer (score 1):

Fully described in http://blog.agilelogicsolutions.com/2011/05/struts-2-interceptors-before-between.html

You can have interceptor:

1. Before Action
2. Between Action and Result
3. After View Rendered

As mentioned in the site here are code samples

Before Interceptor

```
public class BeforeInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
      // do something before invoke
       doSomeLogic();
      // invocation continue    
      return invocation.invoke();
    }
  }
}
```

Between action and result

```
public class BetweenActionAndResultInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
      // Register a PreResultListener and implement the beforeReslut method
      invocation.addPreResultListener(new PreResultListener() { 
        @Override
        public void beforeResult(ActionInvocation invocation, String resultCode) {
          Object o = invocation.getAction();
          try{
            if(o instanceof MyAction){
              ((MyAction) o).someLogicAfterActionBeforeView();
            }
            //or someLogicBeforeView()
          }catch(Exception e){
            invocation.setResultCode("error");
          }
        }
      });

      // Invocation Continue
      return invocation.invoke();
    }
  }
}
```

After View Rendered

```
public class AfterViewRenderedInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
      // do something before invoke
      try{
        // invocation continue    
        return invocation.invoke();
      }catch(Exception e){
        // You cannot change the result code here though, such as:
        // return "error"; 
        // This line will not work because view is already generated  
        doSomeLogicAfterView();
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to use finally instead of catch for the logic to do after view generated. But I didn't test it.