# Can we return any class object to Interceptor from action class

Tags: java, struts2

Can we return any object type to an interceptor from action class methods instead of returning a string, then return a string from the interceptor to identify the required result?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just need a logger type phenomenon inside which i also need to reflect the pre-image and the post-image of the changed object

Comment: You can get your object inside interceptor. There is no need to return it from action method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts 2 interceptor that runs after the page executes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475415/struts-2-interceptor-that-runs-after-the-page-executes)

Comment: Not really a dupe, for two reasons: this question asks about non-string action return values, and requires using a `PreResultListener` rather than something that executes after rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, yes, if you bypass the "invoke" mechanism. Should you? Likely not.

The cleaner, canonical S2 approach would be to expose a property to your interceptor, defined by an interface the action implements. For example, you might call it `Revisionable` or `RevisionAware` and expose a pair composed of `before` and `after` references.

In your interceptor you'd check for that interface, in pseudocode:

```
if (action instanceof Revisionable) {
    return processRevisionablePair();
}
```

You might include a method in the interface that handles action- or model-specific revisions that returns an appropriate result, or if it's the same across the application, you could wrap up the functionality in the interceptor and have "modified" and/or "unmodified" results, etc.

Action methods that return something *other* than a string deviates from framework expectations, leading to multiple ways to handle different actions, multiple ways to test, and so on. Yuck. Keep things consistent, and avoid a layer of documentation and differentiation that isn't really necessary.

Lastly, to return a result based on the action method return value, you need to implement a `PreResultListener` that will provide the result name. Results have already been rendered after `invoke` returns as [per the docs](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/writing-interceptors.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can return instance of `Result` interface directly from your action.